# Azure scale up instance in case of fail

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is there any possibility to create a rule that will be checking VM availability and create another one in case of first VM failure (stops responding via HTTP address)? As I know availability set is not the thing that I need because you need at least two VM's for it. Auto scale can scale VM's by CPU load and queries, so it's not good for me too. I need to run a single VM, the other one should be created only if the first VM stops responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try writing an Automation Workbook that would do this - spin in a loop and chekc status and bring a VM up, but it can be somewhat complex... alternatively, you can use a third-party tool [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com) that could start a VM in Azure when another one goes down.
Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with CloudMonix

Comment: Well, I guess, it's the only possible for me way to do this. Thanks.